# LEGO for a 1 year old

Tags: sets, shopping

I have a son who has just turned one. I like my LEGO and my desk at work is covered in minifig's etc, the problem is my wife isn't as keen on them. I was wondering can anyone recommend a set that would be appropriate for me to get for my son so I can bring my hobby home without feeling the wrath of my wife, or is it a bit too soon to introduce him to LEGO?

Comment: Be honest. You're buying these for yourself? or your son? :) If for yourself, don't bother. Duplo is incredibly frustrating to play with if you're used to Lego. If for your son, I suspect at 1 he won't be that into it, but eventually he'll figure it out. But there's no hurry, and it won't scratch your lego itch.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

LEGO Group also did a range called [LEGO Baby or Primo](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Baby), which was pretty much suitable from birth.

It's not currently in production, but does come up on ebay and the like now and again, and is slightly inter-usable with Duplo and hence standard LEGO blocks.

Items ranged from things like this rattle, with chewable petals:

[image: Flower Teething Rattle]

To the more "advanced" building sets:

[image: Happy Explorers Stack 'n' Learn]

My sons both enjoyed their Stacking Jungle Set, and the Bathtime Boat is still going strong ;)

Comment: Lol, this pic is epic :D [Flower Teething Rattle](http://i.stack.imgur.com/gBHA5.jpg)

Answer (score 12):

LEGO bricks aren't suitable for children under 3 as they are considered a potential choking hazard.

LEGO also sell a [DUPLO](http://duplo.lego.com/en-us/Default.aspx) brand of construction toys which are twice the size of regular bricks. DUPLO bricks are designed for children aged 1½ to 5 years old.

[image]

Comment: Note that some of the DUPLO sets include shovels, flags, and other small items which could be dangerous.  So stash those bits away for a couple years...

Answer (score 7):

There is also a non-Lego product from Megabloks that is really good for young children.  They studs on those blocks are rounded so they're easier to kids to get them to "lock" together.  While not as sturdy as some of the Lego products, they do seem appropriate for real young children.

Comment: Seconding this, they are actually QUATRO-scaled and would sorta link up to the DUPLO/regular sized stuff but only on the bottom. Either way I got 2 large boxes of them and all 3 kids love them also because the builds get HUGE very quickly.

Answer (score 6):

In addition to DUPLO, there is also [QUATRO](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/default.aspx?theme=Quatro). They are, as expected, 4X the size and impressively compatible with standard sized and DUPLO. I inherited some, so have no idea if they are still made or sold.